# Modifying a running script and having it reload without killing it (php)

Tags: php, bash, shell, gnu-screen

I have a gameserver running on Debian where players can edit an (already-running) php script via web to modify the game. However, once changes are made to the script and saved, the affects of the changes only happen once the script is killed and rebooted (I have to do this manually in terminal). Without giving shell access to users, how can the script know to reload a new version of itself once changes have been made? The script is running in a GNU Screen.

Although my overall knowledge on GNU screen, php, and linux commands are limited, I think there has to be a way for this to be done.

What would the easiest way be?

**EDIT**
To clarify, the script that people modify is a basic script that usually reads a server output log. So when the script sees "PLAYER_DIED" it writes to a file, which in turn is read by the server and does some stuff, like spawn a zone.
People edit this script right now with a basic web-based text editor linked to the php source code

Comment: Allowing users to edit a running script seems to be less than sensible. If your server is hosted then you're more than likely violating your Terms of Use.

Comment: I host this off my own hardware, and it is perfectly acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous ways to achieve this, but it's hard to tell which method is the best since you don't share any of your source code.

Why not restart it within the same script that you use to let the players modify the script?

Another solution is to have a small cron-script that runs every minute to check if the file was changed. If so it will then restart the instance. In a worst case scenario, the players have to wait a minute until the changes are seen.

Also I'm wondering if you are using some kind of deamon that is running the actual script that is edited by the players or if you are running that script directly.

Comment: I edited my question clarifying how the script works, hopefully this clears something up :) And there is no deamon, its just a text editor linked directly to the php source

Comment: One possibility is: when the timestamp of the php file is changed, restart the screen session. Would this be feasible?

Comment: Possibly, but to me it seems you'd want to have a deamon running instead. Here's an [excellent guide](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/)

Comment: @Marcus most of that stuff is greek to me, as I said above, I barely have a handle on any of these concepts

Comment: @Kevin, it's not too late to learn. I've never done something like this myself so I'm merely sharing my thoughts on how I think I would do it ;)

Comment: hehe, I spent most my time reading "what is a deamon", looks powerful, but maybe overkill for this ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity: what kind of game is this?

Answer (score 1):

Shooting in the dark here.. but it seems like you will need to use PHP's process control functions to terminate the script and run it again once you know the script has changed. I have not tested this (at all), so take it with a grain of salt:

```
// signal handler function
function sig_handler($signo)
{

     switch ($signo) {            
         case SIGHUP:
             // Asked to restart. I guess you will need to call `exec` to start a new instance before terminating

             break;
         default:
             // handle all other signals
     }

}

// setup signal handler
pcntl_signal(SIGHUP,  "sig_handler");

// Send restart signal to self (after you detect the script was modified):
posix_kill(posix_getpid(), SIGHUP);
```

There are limitations of using [pcntl_* functions](http://cl.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) : PHP needs to be run as a CGI and you need to compile php with `--enable-pcntl`. Since you said you own the hardware, I guess this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The game server freaks out when I use php cgi, mainly because it tries to spit out html too (don't ask). the command line php (cli) works fine