# How do I reload a file in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I am including a File which is used as a plugin in a PHP application to later instantiate the class in it using ReflectionClass. Now, I would like to reload the whole file on runtime, so I can update the code while my program is running. Is there any way I could do this?

Here's some of my code:

```
$info = new \SplFileInfo("plugins/".$name."/".$main);
include("plugins/".$name."/".$main);
$class = new \ReflectionClass($name."\\".$info->getBasename(".php")); //Taking care of using the correct namespace
$this->class = $class->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
```

Running the exact same code twice results in the program crashing.

Edit: My plugin architecture consists of a PluginManager which is supposed to load and unload plugins. Unloading works fine. There's also a EventManager which is used by the plugins to subscribe to specific Events my Program or other Plugins can fire. After unloading a plugin, the object of the Plugin itself is never used again by anything.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to build a classical "program" that is meant to be executed in a separate process. For such php is a _very_ uncommon language... I am not aware that it is possible to drop definitions to be able to redeclare things like classes or name spaces, sorry. You might want to think about spawning child process for this, then certainly you can load the files for each child you spawn. But somehow I doubt this is what you want to do. Maybe you want to tell us a bit more about your architecture?

Comment: Added to the question, thanks.

Comment: Why on earth would one want to chose _php_ as a language for such?!?

Comment: How does one interact with that "program"? Does it have a UI? What purpose does it server, so what features does it offer? How is it launched? I am asking all this because I _still_ think that this is a huge miss understanding...

Comment: Just to add to arkascha's comment: it seems you are trying to do at runtime what should be configuration options that affect the whole script. You would be better off configuring each request to use specific plugins instead of trying to modify classes definitions during runtime. Unless I'm misunderstanding your goal..

Answer (score 0):

It seems not quite good idea for PHP application. I'm not sure, but may be [here is the answer on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904678/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-reload-php-code-while-script-is-running) and [here is the link on RunKit doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) (found there in the comments)

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: I know that it's not so hard, but sometimes I have some specifying questions about the topic, and of course I can't ask via comment before I have this privilege and I'm forced to create an answer. Before I make right decision - another member already asked topic starter and write accepted solution. The simplest questions (although even there I can have mistakes, it can be, it will be gone) is not so interesting and solutions appears earlier than I even read the quest. :) sry about that..